# Changing directory color with zsh + Prezto

Tags: zsh, prezto

I am using [Prezto](http://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) + zsh as my shell. I would like to change the color of
directories when I `ls` my directory. For instance, here is what I currently
have:

> [image: My crappy ls listing]

Obviously, this is no fun, as I’m hardly able to read my directories because the
blue is so dark. I’d like to change it to white or orange or something lighter.

This dark blue is specific only to directories. Files show up in a nice white
text. Where and what settings must I find to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on your `ls`. BSD `ls` uses the environment variable `LSCOLORS`; coreutils `ls` uses `LS_COLORS` instead. See your man page.

The [`utility` module of Prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/blob/master/modules/utility/init.zsh) uses `dircolors` (if available) to customize the colors of coreutils `ls`, which also comes with coreutils. So if you have coreutils, then you can use `dircolors` to provide actually human-readable color definitions. Read the man page of `dircolors` for details. Prezto reads from `$HOME/.dir_colors` by default, otherwise it just use the default colors defined by `dircolors`. You can of course specify other locations by editing on top of Prezto.

For BSD ls, there's probably no utility comparable to `dircolors`, so one has to manually define `LSCOLORS`. See the `ENVIRONMENT` section of the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) on its format, which should be pretty clear. An example is `LSCOLORS='exfxcxdxbxGxDxabagacad'`, used by Prezto by default. To have it take effect, put it in runcoms, after loading Prezto's utility module.

Comment: Do you mean that if I just specify `dircolors` at the bottom of my .zshrc file, I can change this color? And if so, what would that `dircolors` look like?

Comment: `dircolors` is a command. What's your OS? And do you have coreutils installed?

Comment: I'm on a MacBook with El Capitan. I don't see coreutils in `/usr/libexec/` so I don't believe so.

Comment: Well, `coreutils` is a package... But if you don't know what it is, chances are you don't have it.

Comment: I would seriously recommend [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) though. On OS X you can easily install `coreutils` with `brew install coreutils` (requires Homebrew, obviously), then putting coreutils' libexec before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`. I don't want to get into religious conflicts, but after you use coreutils for a while, you'll find BSD utilities shipped with OS X like crippled cousins. Seriously.

Comment: Would it matter which file in runcoms? I was thinking zshrc but don't have much reasoning for that.

Comment: Read `man zsh`, `STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES` section. It clearly indicates which file is for what. Here you want ls to show colors only in an interactive shell, and it doesn't matter whether it's a login shell or not, so it should go into `zshrc`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92663/discussion-between-cole-bittel-and-4ae1e1).

Answer (score 25):

**Update**

I've seen this answer still getting attention, so here's an update. Instead of messing with individual colours as below, simply adjust the `Minimum Contrast` within `Preferences ... -> Profiles -> Colors`. I set mine to `60`.

[image]

**Original answer**

The easier way to do this is to change the colour scheme of your terminal. For example if you are using iTerm2 on a Mac then:

- Launch iTerm2
- type `CMD+i`
- In the "Colors" tab, change the setting for "Blue" (and potentially the "Bright" equivalient)
- In the "General" tab, click "Copy Current Settings to Selected Profile"

If you want to revert back to the defaults you can always select a value from the "Color presets..." dropdown in the "Colors" tab.

Do the equivalent in your favourite terminal if you don't use iTerm2 on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the party but I found the answer here: https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/issues/1539

Run in the Terminal or add to your `.zshrc` file

`export LSCOLORS="ExGxBxDxCxEgEdxbxgxcxd"`

Answer (score 0):

Only adding this comment in case someone reads this thread in the future.

eleov eleove's answer, while correct, is missing a line before the `export LSCOLORS="..."` command. You must also include:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
```

source:
https://infosecmonkey.com/adding-color-to-your-macos-ls-output/